# Getting warning about heap size when running emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, heap-size

I am seeing the message below when launching emulator.

```
Warning: requested ram_size 1536M too big, reduced to 1024M

emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 
96MB
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 384MB
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: Error
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: failed to get the latest version,
skipping  check (current version '25.1.7'
```

Comment: Thats not an error its just a warning. And if it says that your app failed to start but there is an icon of your app in your window start the app by clicking it. Same error happens with me too

Comment: Use genymotion for effective emulators. https://www.genymotion.com/